# Assertion Control in Ldap DelRequest

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am facing problem sending Assertion Control with LDAP DelRequest message.

I am getting this error in openLdap server:

```
591950a9 begin get_filter

591950a9 conn=1004 op=1 DISCONNECT tag=120 err=2 text=error decoding filter

591950a9 conn=1004 op=1 DISCONNECT tag=120 err=2 text=error decoding filter

591950a9 conn=1004 op=1 do_delete: get_ctrls failed
```

My code snippet looks like below:

```
        std::string keyy = "Plan=*";
        struct berval * berEncodedFilter = ber_bvstr(keyy.c_str());

        LDAPControl* serverControl[2];
        return_code = ldap_control_create(LDAP_CONTROL_ASSERT, 0, berEncodedFilter, 0, &(serverControl[0]));
        serverControl[1] = NULL;

        return_code = ldap_delete_ext(m_connection, dn.c_str(), serverControl, 0, &msgID);

        ber_bvfree(berEncodedFilter);
        ldap_control_free(serverControl[0]);
```

Is there an issue in this code?
  Please help.